# Theorycrafting a program to create mnemonic major trigger words and need some advice

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, brute-force, mnemonics

[Here is the mnemonic major system:](http://www.rememberg.com/Mnemonic-Systems/Major--The-Major-System-for-remembering-numbers)

Basically, the table is as follows:

```
0: z or s
1: t or d
2: n
3: m
4: r
5: l
6: g or j
7: k or c
8: f or v
9: p or b
```

So as an example the number "31415" would be "mtrtl". Then you just fill in with any vowels or spaces that makes the gibberish into words so you might do something like "meteor tail" ("mtr tl" with vowels in between the letters). Now you can just think of "meteor tail" and decode it to remember "31415".

There are already tools [like this](http://www.phoneticmnemonic.com/lookup.php?num=31415&submit=Lookup) but for a lot of numbers they don't work. Here is where the programming comes in.

I notice if you google some gibberish it often comes up with a good guess for the word you might have meant. I was thinking of perhaps making a database of words by googling consonant strings with every combination of vowels between them to see which has the most Google results and listing the top 10 for each one, but I doubt Google would appreciate that very much.

I haven't started coding yet but I feel like a dictionary won't cut it for this, but maybe it could work. Is there a list (just a long list, no definitions or formatting) of English words that I could use? Is there a more effective way of going about this rather than just brute-forcing every vowel combination with every sequence of consonants and recording which ones show in in a dictionary?

Thanks for reading! C# is my preferred language so I'm just going to tag it as such.

Comment: You would probably preprocess your dictionary by stripping out all the vowels. Than you can find exact matches fast by looking the consonant combination up in a hash table

Comment: english word dictionaries can be found [on the internet](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: An alternative to the dictionary would be to build a directed acyclic word graph (DAWG) of words with the vowels stripped. Although building it would be somewhat more complex than building a dictionary as Niklas suggested, it would likely be smaller and faster to search.

Answer (score 0):

The most known free English dictionary is [**WordNet**](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Actually, it is not really a dictionary, but a lexical database, but you can use one of its tables as dictionary.

But it seems that the page you are refering to with the description of the [**Mnemonic major system**](http://www.rememberg.com) has already done this! When you enter a number on this websites, it seems to search WordNet (and much more!).

Good luck.